# How to create subdomain in Nginx server on UBUNTU 14.04

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-14.04, digital-ocean

I am trying to create subdomain for my blogging site in digitalocean. I have added a cname record in my domain section. I have created file named blog in `/etc/nginx/sites-available` and added the following lines-

```
server {
   listen  80;
   server_name blog.mydomain.com;
   location / {
          root   /usr/share/nginx/blog;
          index index.php index.html index.html;
   }
}
```

And also added `include /etc/nginx/sites/enabled/*;` in my `nginx.conf` file. But still it shows "This site can’t be reached." What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

did you add symbolic link from /etc/nginx/sites-available/ folder to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled ?

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/filename /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/filename
```

Comment: check configuration via

nginx -t

Comment: Yes. I did check. It's showing me that the syntax is OK.  And the nginx.conf   test is successful.

Comment: ping your subdomain address then compare the IP address with your server IP